# Latex listings: title above the listing should be different than the title in the list of listings

Tags: latex, listings

You can create a listing in Latex like this

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={foo}]
    test
\end{lstlisting}
```

Above the listing is written "foo", in the list of listings is also written "foo".

I want that in the list of listings is written "bar" instead of "foo". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[bar]foo}]
    test
\end{lstlisting}
```